# Gitversion rolled back the version number for my NuGet packages in AzureDevops build pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gitversion

**The problem:**

Until two days ago the version generated by GitVersion worked correctly but now suddenly it rolled from 1.421 to 1.407.

[image]

**My Environment:**

**Azure DevOps:**

Multiple version of Azure DevOps build pipelines that build 10+ NuGet packages that use GitVersion MsBuild task with Mainline mode configured.

For my build pipelines versions I have the following structure:
A version for Microsoft Hosted agent and a version of Self Hosted agent.

For each version I have the following pipelines:

   - Restore, Build, Pack, Unit Test and Publish Symbols and to NuGet feed.
   - Restore, Build, Pack, Publish
   - Restore, Build, Unit Test

**GitVersion 5.3.0**

I have set it to increment the Minor number for each new commit into my master branch. Also worth to I don't use any other sources for calculating the version as this is the most comfortable approach for me and worked pretty nice until now.

**GitVersion yml config:**

```
next-version: 1.1
mode: Mainline
branches: 
  feature:
    tag: alpha
    increment: Inherit
  master:
   increment: Minor
   tag: ''
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

**What I've tried to do:**

- From reading the logs I noticed that Git Version outputs this message: "Skipping fetching, if GitVersion does not calculate your version as expected you might need to allow fetching or use dynamic repositories.", so i used dynamic repositories but the same result is generated.. :(

I don't know what else I should do to debug this.. I'm thinking is a problem with the GitVersion cache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which branch are we looking at here? What was the change in Git for version `1.407.`? Just a regular commit, or was it a merge? What else might have happened in the Git repository between version `1.421.` and `1.407.`? Any other merges that might have happened? Also, have you tried the latest version of GitVersion?

Comment: Hi David, any update for this issue? Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but due to bank holiday I didn't had access to my work computer.

Comment: @Asbjørn Ulsber master branch, just a regular commit and didn't update to the last version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source for my problem. I was working in my project and committed a change before pulling the latest changes from master. Next after pulling the changes I observed that my commit was placed like 6 or 7 commits back in history.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what else I should do to debug this.. I'm thinking is a
> problem with the GitVersion cache?

1.If the `#1.421` and following `#1.407` in your pic are **both** `master` branch:

I think there's possibility that you have `git reset --hard` or other action recently in your git repo which caused this behavior:

[image]

2.If the `#1.421` and following `#1.407` in your pic are not for same branch, then it's expected behavior cause the version number is different per branch.(The `master` and `feature` have different rules)

[image]

The version of the pipeline is `next-version: 1.1`+ number of valid commits (total commits-the commits deleted during git reset) for one branch. So you need to check:

1.if you modify the version in GitVersion yml recently

2.if you do git reset --hard action recently

3.if the two versions come from two difference branches, the `feature` branch and `master` branch have different commits history and different numbers of commits. So it's expected behavior to see different version.

Comment: 1. I didin't modified GitVersion yml recently. 
2. I didin't execute "git reset --hard"
3. Maybe its this one because I was trying out something with my build pipeline and I merged the commits back to master.

Comment: @David In my test, {the version number from this task}={next-version: 1.1}+{valid commits for one specific branch}. So if you didn't modify the yml or `git reset`, then there should be some changes for your branch history. (Check the history of one branch and I think you would find something useful~)

Comment: I think I found the source for my problem.  I was working in my project and committed a change before pulling the latest changes from master. Next after pulling the changes I observed that my commit was placed like 6 or 7 commits back in history.. What can I do in Gitversion config to avoid these types of problems? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry but I have no good idea about how to configure the GitVersion config file cause it's a third-party extension, not Micorosft's. Maybe you can get some help from [their Document](https://gitversion.net/docs/configuration) or open a new issue [here](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues). Also just personal guess, you can try increasing the number of  `next-version` according to `my commit was placed like 6 or 7 commits back`, hope it helps~